# Cannot assign Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down to apps, Ubuntu holds these shortcuts to itself

Tags: shortcut-keys

I try to assign assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> in any application but the system doesn't passes the hotkey to an application. Any other hotkeys are passed normally to VC Code for example. How I can release hotkeys from Ubuntu system to use them myself?

[I try to assign assign Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down in VC Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVBr.png)

I think Ubuntu holds these shortcuts to switch between desktops. I changed shortcuts to switch between desktops to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> in settings, but the problem stays anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> hotkeys from use by the system and assign switching between desktops to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd>**

1. View the list of all hotkeys available to change

   ```
   gsettings list-recursively | grep org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
   ```
2. Check which hotkeys are used by the system to switch between desktops

   ```
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down
   ```
3. Release the hotkeys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> from use by the system

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"   
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"  
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[]"  
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "[]"
   ```
4. Assign switching between desktops to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd>

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Super><Alt>Left']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Super><Alt>Right']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super><Alt>Up']"
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super><Alt>Down']"
   ```

Good luck!